# Can a Swordmage use Spikes of Agony with every use of Aegis of Assault, or only once per encounter?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, swordmage

The Swormage has the 7th level Encounter Power **Spikes of Agony**. This Encounter has an effect that includes the At-Will **Aegis of Assault**. When attacking with Aegis of Assault you normally make a melee basic attack, *however* Spikes of Agony says that you can use it in place of Aegis of Assault's melee basic attack.

Can you replace that melee attack every time you use Aegis of Assault, or, because it is an Encounter Power, can you do it only once per encounter?

Answer (score 4):

#### You can only use Spikes of Agony once per encounter.

<sub>(Unless you have a way to refresh encounter powers.)</sub>

Aegis of Assault lets you make basic melee attacks at-will under certain conditions. Spikes of Agony lets you use it *instead of* an Aegis of Assault basic melee attack, but it is an encounter power and so can only be used once per encounter. Aegis of Assault can continue to grant you melee basic attacks after you use Spikes of Agony, but once you have expended Spikes of Agony you can no longer replace those basic melee attacks.